# How to get a Hong Kong visa from Pakistan?

Tags: visas, hong-kong, pakistan

There is no Hong Kong embassy in Pakistan. How should I apply for a visa and how should I pay for it if I have to send documents?

Comment: Why would you expect there to be one? Hong Kong is part of China. Do you have an embassy of Puerto Rico or an embassy of Greenland?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Hong Kong does have its own immigration system and issues its own visas, while Puerto Rico and Greenland do not. That doesn't mean they have their own embassies, but it doesn't strike me as an unreasonable question.

Comment: @ZachLipton That's not strictly correct. Greenland, HK and PR are three separate cases. PR = considered domestic USA. HK = Separate immigration, administered by HKSAR government. Greenland = [Separate immigration](http://naalakkersuisut.gl/en/About-government-of-greenland/About-Greenland/Coming-to-Greenland), administered by Denmark, particularly since Greenland is not Schengen like Denmark is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to the Embassy of China in Pakistan](http://pk.chineseembassy.org/eng/lsfw/va/t1563596.htm), you can apply for a visa through them or by sending your documents [directly to the Hong Kong Immigration Department in Hong Kong](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit_transit.html) (see the information under the tab marked "Applying," specifically "Submission of Application"). You could also hire a visa courier service to assist with this. The "Applying" tab also lists the documents you must submit and all the other requirements.

They caution that it can take a month or longer to receive a response.

If you bring your documents to the Chinese Embassy, you'll pay the Embassy the listed fees. If you apply directly:

> the fees in the form of a cashier order or a bank draft should be sent together with the application. The cashier order or bank draft should be issued by a bank which has a connected bank in the HKSAR and made payable to "The Government of the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region". No cash should be sent with the application.

The above links are for a vist visa. Information for other types of visas may be [found on the Immigration Department website.](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [China Highlights](https://www.chinahighlights.com/hong-kong/visa.htm), you need to visit China's embassy or consulate for a Hong Kong visa.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the "China highlight" travel agency? (Just asking because it seems a strange resource to quote instead of the official sites.)

Comment: no, googled it and it was the first site I found